# Delete regex matches placed inside other regex matches

Tags: java, regex

I have two regexes. I want to delete all matches of second one if they are placed inside matches of first one. Basically, nothing can be matched in what was already matched. Example:

**First regex** (bold) - `c\w+` finds words beginning with `c`

**Second regex** (underlined) - `me` finds `me`

Result: **cam̲e̲l crim̲e̲ care cool** m̲e̲dium m̲e̲lt hom̲e̲

The `me` in c-words are matched too. Want I want is: **camel crime care cool** m̲e̲dium m̲e̲lt hom̲e̲

Two results of second regex are in results of first regex, I want to delete them, or just don't match them at all. Here's what I tried:

```
String text = "camel crime care cool medium melt home";

static final Pattern PATTERN_FIRST = Pattern.compile("c\w+");
static final Pattern PATTERN_SECOND = Pattern.compile("me");

// Save all matches
List<int[]> firstRegexMatches = new ArrayList<>();
for (Matcher m = PATTERN_FIRST.matcher(text); m.find();) {
    firstRegexMatches.add(new int[]{m.start(), m.end()}); 
}

List<int[]> secondRegexMatches = new ArrayList<>();
for (Matcher m = PATTERN_SECOND.matcher(text); m.find();) { 
    secondRegexMatches.add(new int[]{m.start(), m.end()}); 
}

// Remove matches of second inside matches of first
for (int[] pos : firstRegexMatches) {
        Iterables.removeIf(secondRegexMatches, p -> p[0] > pos[0] && p[1] < pos[1]);
}
```

In this code I store all matches of both into list then try to remove from the second list matches placed inside first list matches.

Not only does this not work, but I'm not sure it's very efficient. Note that this a simplified version of my situation, which contains more regexes and a large text. Iterables is from Guava.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to remove them from the string, so that the result is `"cal cri care cool medium melt home"`?  If so, your question isn't clear on this.  Also, I don't see any code that actually removes anything from a string.  Also, what is `Iterables`?  It's not in the standard Java library, so what is it?  Apache? Guava? I can't tell what's going on without that info, but it looks like your `removeIf` is removing one of the pairs from the `List` you created.  It's not removing anything from the string.

Comment: Also, your first pattern finds any "c" whether it's at the beginning of a word or not.

Comment: @ajb All matches were saved to a list. I'm trying to remove from them from the second regex list. Iterables is from Guava, I could not use the java 8 function

Comment: I'm afraid you've just added to the confusion.  Looking at "what I want", now it seems like you're not trying to delete anything, but instead you want to upper-case some occurrences of "me" but not others.  I don't see any code that upper-cases anything, or replaces "me" with "ME".  I think you need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. You see, what I want is to not match anything in what was already matched, the most efficiently possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can achieve something like this merging both expressions into one.

```
(^c\w+)|\s(c\w+)|(\w*me\w*)
```

If you match against this regex every match will be either a word starting with "c" followed by some word-characters or a word containing "me". For every match you then either get the group:
(1) or (2) indicating a word starting with "c" or
(3) indicating a word containing "me"

However note that this only works in case you know the delimiter of the words, in this case a \s character.

Example code:

```
    String text = "camel crime care cool medium melt home";

    final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(^c\\w+)|\\s(c\\w+)|(\\w*me\\w*)");

    // Save all matches
    List<String> wordsStartingWithC = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> wordsIncludingMe = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text); m.find();) {
        if(m.group(1) != null) {
            wordsStartingWithC.add(m.group(1));
        } else if(m.group(2) != null) {
            wordsStartingWithC.add(m.group(2));
        } else if(m.group(3) != null) {
            wordsIncludingMe.add(m.group(3));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(wordsStartingWithC);
    System.out.println(wordsIncludingMe);
```

---

I'd recommend to **simplify this by taking a somewhat different approach**.
As you seem to know the word limiter, namely the whitespace character, you can get a collection of all words simply by splitting the original string.

```
String[] words = "camel crime care cool medium melt home".split(" ");
```

You then simply iterate over all of these.

```
for(String word: words) {                
    if(word.startsWith("c")) {
        // put in your list for words starting with "c"
    } else if (word.contains("me")) {
        // put in your list for words containing "me"
    }
}
```

This will result in two lists without duplicate entries, as the second if statement will only be executed in case the first one fails.

Comment: I used the first approach for my code thinking that matcher.group() would give what group in regex made the match. If for example, the match was a word beginning with `c`, it would return 1 because group 1 made the match. However this is not the case. Do you know any way to get this value?

Comment: @Croutonix I just added an example of how it could work taking the first approach. As I currently don't have an IDE I just compiled and run it on tutorialspoint on which it seemed to work however.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it possible to combine the two Regexes? For example, the `me` after `c` can be found using one Regex with this code:

```
((?<=c)|(?<=c\w)|(?<=c\w{2})|(?<=c\w{3})|(?<=c\w{4})|(?<=c\w{5}))me
```

Check it out here: https://regex101.com/r/bfNkvF/2

Comment: No this cant work because I need to do two separate things with the regexes and with this I can't differenciate them (can I?)

Comment: No, you can't unless you used groups or another regex.